# how to turn on wifi programatically in flutter and android?

Tags: android, flutter, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to create app functionality to turn on WIFI programmatically.
In android wifi.setWifiEnabled method was deprecated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ask the permission in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Then in the activity file, you can disable wifi

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()
```

Comment: not working https://prnt.sc/aN2ZU6Qm_peb